# Modify @Input array and copy to local array in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

Array from parent component-A to child component-B, In component-B I want to remove some entries and copy to a local array in component-B

**In app-compa.ts:**

```
User=[{id:1,name:"ABC"}{id:1,name:"XYZ"}{id:2,name:"DEF"},...]
```

**In app-compa.html:**

```
<app-compb [usr]="User"></app-compb>
```

**In app-compb.ts:**

```
sp_usr:any[]
@Input usr:Any
sp_usr=usr <-- This required
```

I need to copy data from "usr" to "sp_usr" and remove repetitive id

**expected:**

```
sp_usr=[{id:1,name:"ABC"},{id:2,name:"DEF"},...]
```

Answer (score 1):

clone array like this , after cloning of array you can remove entry from cloned one and it will not affect original array.

```
const sp_usr= Object.assign([], usr);
//or 
const sp_usr=[...usr]; //es6 spread operator
```

or To do a deep copy of an object you need an external library, this allows to modify object with in array without affecting original one

```
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
const sp_usr = cloneDeep(usr);     // This works for [{a:1}, {b:2}]
```

Comment: @Eliseo- yes thats ES6 let me add that also